# pydot graphviz edge attribute arrowhead not working

Tags: graphviz, pydot

I want to construct a directed graph using python. How do I get the arcs to show arrowheads?

```
import graphviz and gv
import pylab

g1 = gv.Graph(format='png')

g1.node("A")
g1.node("B")

g1.edge("A", "B", arrowhead='normal')

g1.edge_attr.update(arrowhead="normal", arrowsize='2')
g1.graph_attr.update(directed="true")
g1.view()
print(g1.source) 

filename = g1.render(filename='img/g1')

pylab.savefig('filename.png')
```

What I get out is a graph but no arrow heads. I want the line between A and B to be an arrow pointing to B:

[image: Graph but no arrowheads]

The line

```
print(g1.source)
```

gives

```
graph {
graph [directed=true]
edge [arrowhead=normal arrowsize=2]
A
B
A -- B [arrowhead=normal]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet exactly the same problem in ***pygraphviz==1.6***.

I am not sure if it behaves the same, but you can have a try

we have to **define the graph as a directed graph** before editing any of the edge attributes.

```
from pygraphviz import AGraph
A = AGraph(encoding="UTF-8",directed=True)
```

Instead of

```
A = AGraph(encoding="UTF-8")
```